# How does CloudAnt's "dbcopy" attribute on views work?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, cloudant

> Defining a chained view couldn't be simpler, just add a `dbcopy` to your view definition.

That's the only reference to `dbcopy` that I can find in the [Cloudant documentation](https://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html). It's obviously used to create a chained view, but how does it work? What does it do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

*dbcopy* stores the results for your MapReduce operation as documents in the same or a separate database. This would allow you to setup another MapReduce operation on those resultant documents, hence the term 'chained MapReduce'.

The process is described [here](https://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html) but *dbcopy* isn't a recommended solution anymore, which is why it can't be found in the Cloudant documentation.

Comment: Is there a new recommended way of doing chained views?